# striking out a data on the table view in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a set of values in table view. I need to delete/cancel a row. I need to strike out that row intimating the user that it has been cancelled. How would i draw a line on the data of the row/ strike out a row using cocoa?

Answer (score 1):

From IOS 6 :

NSAttributedString has strike through attribute "NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName"

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/